# How to use lambda while creating a new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have below code for demonstrating a Deadlock situation in Java. I am just trying replacing a Runnable object variable with lambda.

```
public class DeadLockExample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)    {
        Shared s1 = new Shared();
        Shared s2 = new Shared();
        Runnable runnable1 = () -> s1.methodOne(s2);
        Runnable runnable2 = () -> s2.methodTwo(s1);

        //below two lines works fine as usual
        new Thread(runnable1).start();
        new Thread(runnable2).start();

        // if I replace above two lines with below two lines, it runs into stackoverflow error
    //    new Thread(() -> s1.methodOne(s2)).start();
    //    new Thread(() -> s2.methodTwo(s1)).start();
    }

    private static class Shared {
        synchronized void methodOne(Shared s)
        {
            s.methodTwo(this);
        }

        synchronized void methodTwo(Shared s)
        {
            s.methodOne(this);
        }
    }
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Both versions would cause an SOE. Problem is not with your construction of `Thread`, it's rather with `methodOne` and `methodTwo` endlessly calling each other.

Comment: No, the first version runs fine, creates the deadlock situation.

Comment: The first version is raising a stackoverflowerror when I run it. 
What's your exact Java version and vendor?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8.0_281

Answer (score 1):

> What's going wrong here?

This is a classic race condition.  When you say:

```
new Thread(runnable1).start();
```

this starts running and calls back and forth between `s1.methodOne(...)` and `s2.methodTwo(...)` until it runs out of stack space.  All of this happens *before* the 2nd runnable is started.  It takes a little bit of time to start a thread running.  If you just put a small sleep in the methods it works.

```
synchronized void methodOne(Shared s) {
    try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* don't do at home */ }
    s.methodTwo(this);
}

synchronized void methodTwo(Shared s) {
    try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* don't do at home */ }
    s.methodOne(this);
}
```

The sleeps slow down the running on your threads and the code then demonstrates the deadlock.

Comment: Upvote for "/* don't do at home */ " ... albeit I fear some people might not get the joke.

Comment: Yeah I hear you @GhostCat.  I always go back and forth between keeping my example code short and doing the right thing.